# Почему один PHP вызов БД работает, а другой по тому же принципу нет?

Tags: php, mysql

Подскажите, почему этот вызов работает:

```
<?php
$postAuthor = $post['author_id'];
$currentUser = $_SESSION['logged_user']->id;
if ($postAuthor === $currentUser) {
require 'myorder.php';
}
?>
```

(в author_id и logged_user id — цифры)

а этот нет:

```
<?php
$postDr = $post['dr'];
$currentDr = $_SESSION['logged_user']->login;
if ($postDr === $currentDr) {
echo '<h2>Ваши актывные заказы</h2>';
require 'active.php';
}
?>
```

(в dr и logged_user login — буквы)

Comment: строки неодинаковые, судя по всему. Выведите их, они хоть на глаз совпадают?

Comment: Потому что оператор `===` не является оператором сравнения строк, используйте операторы по назначению `strcmp($str1,$str2)==0`